# Problems Displaying Functions through Constructor. My Functions Keeps Showing :(

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

(Just started JS and first stack overflow, sorry for any goofs.)

I am trying to figure out how to insert the results of a function through a JS constructor. I am able to do it with simple stuff like strings, but my newbie mind goes blank when I try--and search for answers--in doing it with a simple function.

The JS code:

```
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth, job, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.job = job;
    this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.calculateAge = function () {
        console.log(2018 - this.yearOfBirth);
    }
Person.prototype.intro = function () {
        console.log(this.noun + ' name is ' + this.name + ' ' +this.lastName + ' and is ' + (2018 - this.yearOfBirth));
    }
Person.prototype.lastName = 'Smith';

Person.prototype.noun = function () {
        if(this.gender === 'male'){
        console.log('his');
    } else {
        console.log('her');
    }
}

var craig = new Person('Craig', 1984, 'student', 'male');
var jane = new Person('Jane', 1969, 'designer', 'female');

craig.intro();
jane.intro();
```

The result in console is just a:

```
function () {
        if(this.gender === 'male'){
        console.log('his');
    } else {
        console.log('her');
    }
} name is Craig Smith and is 34
```

What I'm looking for is:
his name is Craig Smith and is 34

(The same for Jane but with her and a lot older.)

Once again, a newbie and am taking some online courses. Looked through the questions a bit and didn't see anything that helped out.

If you can explain this to me I'd greatly appreciate it! Whether links to a site that has the info or if you want to even explaining.

All help is helpful! :)

Comment: The difference between `this.noun` and `this.noun()` is one is the function itself and one actually calls the function

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong:

1. You're not actually invoking the `this.noun` function which is why it's printing the function definition. You want to print what the function returns after it's been invoked.
2. With this in mind you want to call (invoke) the function like this: `this.noun()`
3. It would also be better to have `this.noun()` return the string instead of `console.log` so you get the output you want. So your code becomes this instead:

   ```
   var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth, job, gender) {
       this.name = name;
       this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
       this.job = job;
       this.gender = gender;
   }

   Person.prototype.calculateAge = function () {
           console.log(2018 - this.yearOfBirth);
       }
   Person.prototype.intro = function () {
           console.log(this.noun() + ' name is ' + this.name + ' ' +this.lastName + ' and is ' + (2018 - this.yearOfBirth));
       }
   Person.prototype.lastName = 'Smith';

   Person.prototype.noun = function () {
       if(this.gender === 'male'){
           return 'his';
       } else {
           return 'her';
       }
   }

   var craig = new Person('Craig', 1984, 'student', 'male');
   var jane = new Person('Jane', 1969, 'designer', 'female');

   craig.intro();
   jane.intro();
   ```

Output:

```
his name is Craig Smith and is 34
her name is Jane Smith and is 49
```